# run lambda function with input parameter in serverless framework command line

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have started a aws project with help of serverless framework, but i have one question regarding run lambda function.

How can I run lambda function with input parameters? I can do it via amazon console, lambda test configuration->test event. but I cannot find a correspondning function in serverless, does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**For the lambda part**

You can use `event.json` file:

```
{
  "principalId": "1234",
  "inputVar": "foo"
}
```

and then run `sls function run`.

According to [docs](http://docs.serverless.com/docs/function-run), if don't specify any stage, function will run locally, if you do specify a stage, function will run deployed code in corresponding stage. BUT the docs seems outdated, you also need to pass `-d` flag like:

```
sls function run myFunction -s dev -d
```

This command will invoke your deployed lambda function, with parameters from your local `event.json` file

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/actions/FunctionRun.js#L45) for function run options.

**For APIG integration**

There are some samples in [documentation](http://docs.serverless.com/docs/templates-variables).

If you don't want to use templates, you can just insert related code in your `s-function.json`, inside the endpoint description.

```
  "endpoints": [
  ...

    "requestTemplates": {
      "application/json": {
        "principalId": "$context.authorizer.principalId",
        "apiKey": "$context.identity.apiKey",
        "inputVar": "$input.json('inputVar')"
      }
    }
  ...
  ]
```

Syntax is as described in [API Gateway Accessing the $input Variable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference) doc.

Comment: Thanks Alper, it works for me now. while you metioned -d option, i wonder is there anyway to just upload lambda function and endpoints(api gateway) to amazon without deploy (i mean without create a new version everytime), sometimes, i just want to test if it works on amazon.

Comment: afaik no. auto versioning is always triggered. but you can use prune plugin to delete old versions.

Comment: You can deploy one off function `$ serverless deploy function -f functionName`. It is much faster than deploying the entire project `$ serverless deploy`. It skips the CloudFront update. Here is some sample code - [http://serverless-stack.com/chapters/deploy-the-apis.html](http://serverless-stack.com/chapters/deploy-the-apis.html?utm_source=stackoverflow.com)